# vscode - problem with sftp-Plugin after update

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins, sftp

I updated my vsCode to version 1.78.2 - so my sftp-Plugin from liximomo did not work anymore and so I migrated to the sftp-Plugin from Natizyskunk. Of course it's activated and my config is the same as before in the file .vscode/sftp.json

```
{
"name": "my.server",
"host": "my.server",
"protocol": "sftp",
"port": 2345,
"username": "user_name",
"privateKeyPath": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
"remotePath": "/list/",
"ignore": ["*.scss", "*.json"],
"uploadOnSave": true,
"interactiveAuth": true,
"watcher": {
    "files": "**/*",
    "autoUpload": true,
    "autoDelete": true
}}
```

but it doesn't work anymore - it does not upload after save and there is no upload or download on right-click. Does anyone know, what I can do to make it work again?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "name": "My Server",
    "host": "00.000.000.0",
    "protocol": "sftp",
    "port": 22,
    "username": "root",
    "password": "PASSPSASA475",
    "remotePath": "/public_html",
    "uploadOnSave": true,
    "useTempFile": false,
    "openSsh": false }
```

I use it this way, I think you can try it like this, I hope it works for you. If you are using sftp, you can use Kelvin.vscode-sshfs , Natizyskunk.sftp package. These are the packages I use as sftp

If the answer worked for you, I would be very happy if you put +1

Comment: Sorry, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem is.

In my project folder there are three subfolders with three different sftp-configurations.

```
main
>project1
 >.vscode
files4project1
>project2
 >.vscode
 files4project2
....
```

And it seems, that the new extention is too silly to look into the subfolders - no problem with the old one - I hope it doesn't stay outdated.